# From what timestamp is the output of a command

Tags: shell

I have a program that is downloading some images into a folder. I want to count the number of images in the folder currently. I used a command like `ls -1 download_folder | wc -l`.

But this command takes a lot of time to run(since I have already downloaded a lot of images). While this command is running, my downloader keeps on downloading the images.

And finally, my command returns the count. I wanted to know, from what timestamp this count is. Is it from the instant I started running the command or it gives the current latest count?

Edit:
I tried validating for myself, but could not find any way.
Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if `set -- *; echo $#` would be faster or slower. It still sorts, but only uses shell built-ins.

Comment: @Quasímodo  I assume "a lot of images" is enough to slow `ls -1` significantly. I tried 100,000 files. `ls` takes 0m1.397s; `ls -U` takes 0m0.209s; `set -- *; echo $#` takes 0m8.933s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ls` command is reading the whole directory, and sorting it, and then passing it to `wc`, which does not care about order anyway. It will run *much* faster if you tell `ls` not to sort, as:

```
ls -U | wc -l
```

This will reduce the time window in which new files can be added, and be more accurate. However, there is still a race condition between the additions and the listing, which cannot be overcome. Some file systems hash the names, some append to a linear list, so `ls` may or may not see any additions while it runs.

Comment: where can I read about how my file system handles these cases?

Comment: @satindersingh Each file system type has its specification which includes strengths and weaknesses. I start with Wikipedia "File system" and have ext4 and NTFS partitions. In the absence of explicit locking strategies, I always assume a file system will interleave system calls from different processes in the most inconvenient way. As in quantum mechanics, "anything that is not specifically forbidden is guaranteed to happen eventually".